# my script slows down other scripts

Tags: php, sleep

I use a simple script in order to check previous invitations from MySQL table and send new invitations. But this script keeps server busy and slows down running of other scripts. How should I change it?

```
for ($g=0; $g<500; $g++){
      $lastsent = time() - (86400*30*6); // last 6 months
      $chkinvlast = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (inv_email='$useremail[$g]' AND inv_datesent>'$lastsent')");
      if (@mysql_num_rows($chkinvlast) < 1){
        send_email($useremail[$g],$ltitle,$lbody);
       }else{
        echo "<br>Invitation for $user was NOT sent, because you already sent an invitation in last 6 months";
       }
}
```

Comment: What does "block" mean?

Comment: I mean "prevent running"

Comment: these lines are unlikely to block another script.

Comment: how do you know anther script is 'blocked' what are the symptoms?

Comment: I bet it's locked by native php session implementation, but on Mondays I don't guess

Comment: by friday your just codeing by mashing the keyboard with your head

Comment: @Dagon: and even after that the result is not as bad as in some other stackoverflow questions

Comment: to Dagon: Because any other page does not open/work till the page contains this script completed.

Comment: I think you should know: sometimes a script keeps server busy, and the other accounts experience delays.

Comment: @Sucu -: "keeps busy" != "blocks". Something that is busy is generally just slower, not completely blocked. If you were precise in using terms it would be really helpful.

Comment: @Zerkms: thanks a lot for your comment, I changed and corrected the question.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: So why do you check the same address 500 times?

Comment: You are making 500 calls to mysql with `SELECT *`..OF COURSE it is slow.Modify your code to use that array in an IN condition with only one call.

Comment: @zerkms: I could not get any answer but I think question would be more understandable by your comments.

Comment: @esqew: I will try to change whole script, and try to learn PDO. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for loop

```
$usermails = "(".implode(',',$usermail).")";

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (inv_email IN ($usermails)  AND inv_datesent>'$lastsent')");
```

Or with prepared statements:

```
$usermails = "(".implode(',',$usermail).")";
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($usermails) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE inv_email  IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($usermails);
$row= $stm->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do 500 calls to the server.. Thats the whole and only possible answer. Of course it gets slow then.

Solution is to change your query in this way that it will use a WHERE IN function.

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) for how to adopt it in your situation. In this use you will only do 1 query instead of 500. See how much faster it gets ;-)